# Mongoose findOne.populate scope issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

There is a array of user IDs in currentUser.follow. Each user has  posts with referenceId of PostSchema . Now I want to populate each user's post and store it in an array[userArray]. But due to scope issue the array remains empty. Please show me how I can get all the users with their post in the Array[userArray]

> app.js

```
app.get("/", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    var currentUser =req.user;
    var userArray=[];
    for(let fol of currentUser.follow){
        User.findById(fol).populate("posts").exec(function(err, user){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                console.log(user);    // a user with populated posts
                userArray.push(user);
                console.log(userArray);  //stores user but posts is not populated
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(userArray);  // empty array
});
```

> User Schema

```
var mongoose =require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    posts: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Post"
        }
    ],
    follow: [String]
});
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

> Post Schema

```
var mongoose =require("mongoose");

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    image: String,
    author:{
        id:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref : "User"
        },
        username: String
    },
    createdAt: {type:Date, default:Date.now}
});
module.exports= mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `User.findById` is asynchronous so the second `console.log(userArray);` will excute before the result pushed to `userArray`.

There is a better way to do this with `$in` operator and `async/await`:

```
app.get("/", isLoggedIn, async function(req, res){
  try {
    var currentUser = req.user;
    var userArray = await User.find({_id: {$in: currentUser.follow}}).populate("posts");
    console.log(userArray); 
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```